# Write formula in excel 2013

Tags: excel, ms-office

How with formula in excel convert date 13.12.2016 to 2016-12-13

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your locale and whether it's a string or just an oddly formatted date.

The short answer is

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/"))
```

or

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","-"))
```

and format the result as a date yyyy-mm-dd.